# Как сделать большой шрифт в Label tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

`lbl_admin = Label(admin, text='Меню', font=40, bg='#808080', width=70, height=5) lbl_admin.place(x=100, y=20)`

Нужно сделать большой размер шрифта в Label, но когда я задаю 40 размер, то шрифт остается фиксированным примерно на 14-15, я пробовал менять height и width, но ни что не помогло.
Укажите что я делаю не так.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: label.config(font=("Courier", 44)) тоже не работает ?

Comment: помогло, большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить параметр `config`

```
from tkinter import*

admin=Tk()
admin.title('Windiw')
admin.geometry('800x300')
admin["bg"]="grey25"

lbl_admin = Label(admin, text='Меню', font=5, bg='#808080', width=70, height=5)
lbl_admin.config(font=("Courier", 44))
lbl_admin.place(x=100, y=20)

admin.mainloop()
```

Comment: простите, но проблема не в параметре конфиг, а в аргументах для задания шрифта. #admin["bg"]="grey25" тоже можно записать через конфиг,кому как удобнее.